# geodjango osmgeoadmin how to delete feature?

Tags: django, polygon, geodjango

I'm using geodjango and using the osmgeoadmin model for a few models that have a multi polygon field. It's really cool that it gives you a map and a nice UI and everything, but I can't figure out how to remove an item for the map.

For instance, if a user is drawing out a bunch of polygons and they mess up, the only way to fix it I think is to hit the delete all features link at the bottom and start over. I'm not finding how to remove an individual polygon?

Comment: Good question. I notice you cant remove all nodes of a polygon neither. The last two are not deletable. The problem lays in openlayers function. You could start a bounty for this question!